# Windows 10, node module no such file

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I'm getting the error below and I don't know why.

I tried `npm rebuild node-sass`. Also tried deleting node modules and using `npm install`.

I'm on Windows 10 with npm@4.0.2, node@6.9.1, gulp@3.9.1

```
gulp serve
fs.js:951
  return binding.readdir(pathModule._makeLong(path), options.encoding);
                 ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\Eduardo Pisapia\Documents\sgb-app-test\C:\Users\Eduardo Pisapia\Documents\sgb-app-test\node_modules\megazord-sdk\app'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:951:18)
    at Object.module.exports.load (C:\Users\Eduardo Pisapia\Documents\sgb-app-test\node_modules\megazord-sdk\gulp-load.js:31:4)
    at Object.module.exports.registerAppTasks (C:\Users\Eduardo Pisapia\Documents\sgb-app-test\node_modules\megazord-sdk\megazord-sdk.js:14:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Eduardo Pisapia\Documents\sgb-app-test\gulpfile.js:7:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

Comment: `'C:\Users\Eduardo Pisapia\Documents\sgb-app-test\C:\Users\Eduardo Pisapia\Documents\sgb-app-test\node_modules\megazord-sdk\app'` definitely looks wrong, but I'm not sure what's causing it.

Comment: I dont know if I should put a enviroment variable... I have tried some example but no progress